# how to define symbolic and numeric function in matlab

Tags: matlab

i want to write function like sqrt in matlab witch whether i pass symbol or pass numeric return value like this code:

```
>> syms x;
>> y = sqrt(x)

y =

x^(1/2)

>> y = sqrt(4)

y =

     2
```

my function is :

```
function [ y ] = fx(x)

    if -1<=x && x<=0
        y=-2;
    elseif 2<=x && x<=3
        y=2;
    else
        y=0;
    end
end
```

in actually i want my function be symbolic also numeric

Comment: What do you want in return if you input a symbolic `x`? `y` wouldn't be defined then would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the class of your inputs with [`isnumeric`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnumeric.html) and [isa(x,'sym')](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html). You may also need [`isfloat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfloat.html) and you may also want to detect symbolic functions with [isa(x,'symfun')](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html). So an example `sqrt` function might look like this:

```
function y=sqrt(x)
if isfloat(x)
    y = sqrt(x);
elseif isa(x,'sym')
    y = sqrt(x); % Same but this might be something else
else
    error('sort:InvalidDatatype','Input must be floating point or symbolic.');
end
```

Of course Matlab's `sqrt` already works fine for both floating-point and symbolic inputs. It actually uses a different scheme that you could also use: overloading by creating separate functions for each class and putting each in an @classname (e.g., @double or @sym) folder on the path.